# onload event completes before populating the div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an onload event that works fine. The problem I have is that the 2nd part of the onload event calls another function but this is before the first part is complete.

The first part enters information into an input field, the 2nd part runs a function using the information from that input field.

My problem is that both functions work ok, but the 1st part doesnt get chance to enter the information into the input field and only inputs it afterwards.

When I go live with the page, the first part will be dynamic taking the information from the URL.

```
onload = function(){

var tempURLtest = "http://ahoymearty.co.uk/shipyard/eNqrVipPTSzIzytWsoo2tjQ10TE0MzGFEMYGQEAMGaujlFiUm18EMsMUyLfQAZGWOuhsqAhQeXFBanJmYg5Ig6GZubGOsYW5uY6xmYWZjrG5MdBmSyOQQ8AmF2dngh0HZGaU5uR4uihZmRiZG+oopVYUpBaVOJVm5qQoWaUBDUutBQB8sDOU"
var fromURL =   tempURLtest.split("/")[4];  

//var fromURL   =   window.location.href.split("/")[4]  
document.getElementById("KixCode").value = fromURL

$scope.LoadKixCode()
```

}

Comment: Are you building a component or a controller? Check the component lifecycle events: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture

Comment: basically the $scope.LoadKixCode() runs before the getelementbyid has put in the information so therfore the $scope.LoadKixCode() has nothing to do

Answer (score 0):

when u call the function out if it doesnt take in any parameters then dont include the () like if the function is names function a2(){ /// }, while calling it just call a2 and not a2()